# Why ROS Noetic has its own pybind11, while it's on Ubuntu 20.04 already

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a curiosity!

On Ubuntu 20.04, there is a package called `pybind11-dev`, but also, a ROS version, called `ros-noetic-pybind11-catkin`, I would rather use the one from Ubuntu but, am I going to miss something from the ROS version? Or not?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375575/why-ros-noetic-has-its-own-pybind11,-while-it%27s-on-ubuntu-20.04-already/) by [Thiago Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/70549/thiago-martins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can infer from the name, [pybin11_catkin](https://github.com/ipab-slmc/pybind11_catkin/tree/3edb290e5fb7d1270a31ac9e81f8d64d26802156) is a:

> Catkin wrapper for pybind11

which basically means:

> This repository wraps the recent releases of pybind11 for use in catkin-based projects.

Among other things, this makes it easy/ier to build / use `pybind11` in Catkin (and Colcon) workspaces, and consequently, ROS packages.

Other advantages would be the use of this package across different OS (which may not have `pybind11`, but do support Catkin workspaces/ROS) and a more homogeneous development environment (`pybind11` available at the same version everywhere).

See [ipab-slmc/pybind11_catkin#3](https://github.com/ipab-slmc/pybind11_catkin/issues/3) for what appears to be a discussion around utility of the package. This links to [arturmiller/pybind11_examples](https://github.com/arturmiller/pybind11_examples) for some examples.

> I would rather use the one from Ubuntu

By all means do.

If you are on an OS which packages `pybind11` at a suitable version and you don't need/want to depend on the Catkin wrapped version, then don't use it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thiago Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/70549/thiago-martins/) on 2021-04-11**:
Got it, thank you!

I also thought that, because ROS doesn't recommend mixing Debian packages from both the community repository, and from upstream distribution, that this could be a problem but, things are a bit different with `pybind11`...

Cool!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-11**:\

> I also thought that, because ROS doesn't recommend mixing Debian packages from both the community repository, and from upstream distribution, that this could be a problem [..]

Are you referring to [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages)?

That's specifically about upstream versions of (the core) ROS packages. Not system dependencies.

**Comment by [Thiago Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/70549/thiago-martins/) on 2021-04-11**:
Yes, I was talking about the `wiki/UpstreamPackages`, thank you for your clarication!

Comment: How do I tell `colcon` to use the system-provided `pybind11`?

Comment: I would suggest you post a new question, as Colcon is ROS 2 and the question (answer really) you comment on is specifically about a Catkin-wrapper (ie: ROS 1).

Comment: Yeah, I did, but haven't had any luck: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104322/building-ros2-humble-on-macos-fails-due-to-old-pybind11