# Building ROS2 Humble on macOS Fails Due to Old pybind11

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, macos

I’ve been trying to build Humble for macOS 13.5.2 (on M1). With the help of Discord, I’ve gotten further along, but now I’ve run into an issue I’m not sure how to solve.

When building `python_orocos_kdl_vendor`, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/rmann/ros2_humble/build/python_orocos_kdl_vendor/_deps/python_orocos_kdl-src/python_orocos_kdl/PyKDL/PyKDL.cpp:27:
In file included from /Users/rmann/ros2_humble/build/python_orocos_kdl_vendor/_deps/python_orocos_kdl-src/python_orocos_kdl/PyKDL/PyKDL.h:26:
In file included from /Users/rmann/ros2_humble/install/pybind11_vendor/include/pybind11_vendor/pybind11/pybind11.h:13:
In file included from /Users/rmann/ros2_humble/install/pybind11_vendor/include/pybind11_vendor/pybind11/attr.h:13:
In file included from /Users/rmann/ros2_humble/install/pybind11_vendor/include/pybind11_vendor/pybind11/cast.h:16:
/Users/rmann/ros2_humble/install/pybind11_vendor/include/pybind11_vendor/pybind11/detail/type_caster_base.h:482:26: error: member access into incomplete type 'PyFrameObject' (aka '_frame')
            frame = frame->f_back;
                         ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/pytypedefs.h:22:16: note: forward declaration of '_frame'
typedef struct _frame PyFrameObject;
               ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [_deps/python_orocos_kdl-build/CMakeFiles/PyKDL.dir/PyKDL/PyKDL.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_deps/python_orocos_kdl-build/CMakeFiles/PyKDL.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is due to a bug in the `pybind11` v2.9.1 dependency. The [bug](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/discussions/4333) in that version is allegedly fixed in v2.10.4, possibly earlier.

Brew on macOS installs the latest `pybind11`, v2.11.1, but ros2 doesn’t find that. I don’t know enough about cmake to understand why (perhaps it’s only looking for v2.9.1).

I’m not sure how it even builds for other platforms.

In any case, can anyone recommend a way to resolve this?

Comment: having the same issue